# Django receive e-mails and their attachments

Tags: python, django, email, attachment

In the app I am working I want to get the my e-mails ,let's say from my gmail account. So I setted up with a class that stores the e-mail adress,port, server and password.

I created a function where I get the Subject,Body and From sections, from the gmail account e-mails and I am backing up the mails in a backup folder with ".eml" extension. Also, I have a "mail-list.html" template where a list is being displayed with the above headers and content. All good till here.

Now how can I get the attchment,if any of a message,so I can show in my "mail-list.html" template if there is one.
This stuff with the e-mail is completely new to me so any example code or even pointing me to a direction would be great!

I have checked out some pluggins such as django mailbox, but I want it to be my last resort.

In the app I am working I want to get the my e-mails ,let's say from my gmail account. So I setted up with a class that stores the e-mail adress,port, server and password.

I created a function where I get the Subject,Body and From sections, from the gmail account e-mails and I am backing up the mails in a backup folder with ".eml" extension. Also, I have a "mail-list.html" template where a list is being displayed with the above headers and content. All good till here.

Now how can I get the attchment,if any of a message,so I can show in my "mail-list.html" template if there is one.
This stuff with the e-mail is completely new to me so any example code or even pointing me to a direction would be great!

I have checked out some pluggins such as django mailbox, but I want it to be my last resort.

**UPDATE:**

I have manage to get the attachments like this...

```
#previous code here to get subject,body etc in my function

if message.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
    filenames_list = []           
    for part in message.walk():
        print("part.get_content_maintype ",part.get_content_maintype())
        #find the attachment part - so skip all the other parts

        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart': continue
        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'text': continue
        if part.get('Content-Disposition') == 'inline': continue
        if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None: continue

        #put  attachments in list
        filenames_list.append(filename)
        print ("filenames_list",filenames_list)

        #create context for template
        mail_list['attachment'] = filenames_list
```

So now, I put my filenames in the list , and to use them in my template I put them in the mail_list['attachment'] context.

When filenames are in english I get this: 
 **['myessay.pdf', 'test.odt']**

But when the attachment is in different language(for example greek) I get: **['=?UTF-8?B?zrXOs86zz4HOsc+Gzr8xLmRvYw==?=', '=?UTF-8?B?zrXOs86zz4HOsc+Gzr8yLmRvYw==?=', '=?UTF-8?B?zrXOs86zz4HOsc+Gzr8xMi5kb2M=?=']**

As you can see above there are three attachments in the list seperated by "," .

How to I decode or encode them? I don't know what is appropriate here.

Comment: Which mail service are you using?

Comment: I am using gmail,from browser. It'sworking with any service though..I have tried with office365 too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have figure it out.... I hope this helps others..
I am refering to the part of the code that gets the attachments.

```
#some code before to require the server variable from the model where
#I store all the required fields for the connction(port,e-mail address etc)
...
...
...


pop3 = poplib.POP3_SSL(server) # or "POP3" if SSL is not supported
msg_list = pop3.list()
pop3.list()
#Get messages from server:
messages = [pop3.retr(i) for i in range(1, len(pop3.list()[1]) + 1)]
# Concat message pieces:
messages = ["\n".join(m[1]) for m in messages]
#Parse message intom an email object:
messages = [parser.Parser().parsestr(m) for m in messages]
for message in messages:
    mail_list = {}
    for item in message.items():
        #code to get subject,from,date
         ...
         ...

        #and now to get the attachments of each message

        for part in message.walk():
            #find the attachment part - so skip all the other parts
            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart': continue
            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'text': continue
            if part.get('Content-Disposition') == 'inline': continue
            if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None: continue

                #get filename
                filename = part.get_filename()
                #this is for encoding other than latin-letter-languages
                if decode_header(filename)[0][1] is not None:
                    filename = str(decode_header(filename[0][0]).decode(decode_header(filename)[0][1])
           filenames_list.append(filename)
           mail_list['attachment'] = filenames_list

context['messages'] = mail_list
```

In my template, in order for the files to appear correctly I also have to iterate through the 'attachment' like this:

```
{% for d in messages %}

/*subject,from,date = parts of the message I have got inside the function before the code I am displaying*/

{{ d.subject }}
{{ d.from }}
{{ d.date }}

{% for t in d.attachment %}{{ t }}{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```